# Exception : can't convert from BSON type OID to String

Tags: mongodb

I'm newbie to mongo db  , so here is the question  i'm getting this following error  when try to change name to upper case  in mongodb thru console.
here is the query :

```
t.aggregate([{$project:{name:{$toUpper:"$_id"} , _id:0}}])
```

Also , I have manually inserted all the fields with "_id" as name such as 
"_id" : "joe"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have looks correct, so you should try to find the document that isn't a string. In the shell type this:

```
db.t.find({}).forEach(function(item) { if(typeof item._id !== 'string') { print(item._id); })
```

That will output any IDs that aren't strings.

Comment: just an fyi -- same basic idea -- you could also use the $type operator in the query: t.find( { _id: {$not: {$type: 2 } } } )  // where type 2 == string, type 7 is ObjectId